# How do I stop Outlook 2010 from deleting emails from the server when it retrieves them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When Outlook 2010 retrieves emails from my home email account it automatically deletes them from that server. How do I stop this? I need to be able to see them from my home computer as well. In the Advanced Tab there is no check box or option to leave emails on the server. This is through an Exchange Server and it is set up as IMAP. My home account is not gmail.

Comment: What you describe can't happen. Are you sure you actually use IMAP, not pop or exchange? Also, why not just configure your email to use exchange itself? Outlook 2010 works best with exchange.

Comment: @LPChip An "Exchange" account doesn't remove messages from the server when you view them either (Exchange accounts are basically just extended IMAP accounts). But I fully agree with you, this shouldn't be an option or happen unless the OP is using POP as the account type.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thats what I was trying to say. Reading my comment back, I can understand that you may've read the or exchange part as: this causes it, which of course was not what I meant. Just asking if they're sure its IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to access the e-mail server from home using Outlook Web Access, if it is available to you.

Depending on how your server is actually setup, try this. [Microsoft Support Article on Outlook 2010](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Change-email-account-settings-58b62e89-6a9b-467b-8865-d5633fcacc3f#bm2e)

Scroll down and expand Additional Settings to see, "If you are using an IMAP e-mail account, you can control when items are deleted. Under Purge Options, select or clear the Purge items when switching folders while online check box."

Good Luck